# Laravel how to change "These credentials do not match our records"

Tags: html, laravel

I am new to laravel and I am making a project for school, I wanted to translate the text that when you put a wrong password to my languange but I can't find it's place does anyone know where it is so I can edit it?
Thanks.

Comment: The documentation about [translations in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, it is in
resources/lang/en/auth.php

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the following path:

resources/lang/{lang_folder}/auth.php

The lang_folder depends on your language configuration.